# how to fixed undefined offset if array data is not equal to limit declared in forloop

Tags: php, for-loop

so i have a single row data from my db.. from one id i have

```
id |  prescription
1  |  sildenafil  ()      25 mg ---- #60---1X per day    morning/
   |  lanoxin  ()      25 mg ---- #60---1X per day    morning/
   |  caltrate plus (caco3)       ---- #60---1X per day    evening/
```

i use this loop to display the data above. so first after getting the data i use `explode` to separate those data with '/' at the end.. and then limit the data that is being displayed.

```
<tbody> 
    <?php
    for ($n=0; $n < 10; $n++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php 

      $prescription_array=explode('/',$new_array2[$n]);
            echo $n+1;                      
            ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php 

            for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
                echo "<font size='5'>".$prescription_array[$i]."</font>";
                $i++;
            }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

what im trying to achieve here is after getting the data from my data and separate it.. i want to limit the data that is being displayed to 10.
sample if have those 3 data only 3 will be displayed.. but my problem is since i limit the loop into 10 what happen is if my data consist only less than 10 i get an error.. `Notice: Undefined offset` since the data is less than 10.

is there any better approach to fix this?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break the loop if it exceeds the length

In your case, you can use:

```
if($n > count($new_array2) - 1) break;
```

This stops the first loop. You can also check the other loop with:

```
if($i > count($prescription_array) - 1) break;
```

Comment: so where should i put the if condition exactly inside the for loop?

Comment: You should put if($n > count($new_array2) - 1) break; in the first line within of your first for loop, and if($i > count($prescription_array) - 1) break; in the first line within the second for loop

Comment: if i get it correctly u mean is to put `if($n > count($new_array2) - 1) break;` inside the loop?.

Comment: Yes, because you are checking if the current index ( $n) is available to use

Comment: Another thing is; in your second loop you are using $i++ double, this may cause strange behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Use **[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** instead of for

Replace your this code

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
                echo "<font size='5'>".$prescription_array[$i]."</font>";
                $i++;
            }
```

with this

```
foreach(array_slice($prescription_array, 0, 10) as $key=> $value) { 
    echo "<font size='5'>".$value."</font>";
    $i++;
 }
```

Comment: i already use foreach before but what i wanted is to limit the data that is being displayed to 10.. so i use for loop to limit the result to 10 even if the array is greater than 10. it will only display 10 data.. but what happen is since i use for loop and limit it to 10 if my data is only less than to 10 i get an offset..

Comment: i tried but now i got an offset on the 1st loop. how can i limit the 1st loop depends on the data?

Comment: base on my question both gives an offset.. you did great on the 2nd loop but on the 1st loop i still got the offset error.. the loop returns 1-10.. and since my array data is only 3, 4-10 becomes offset.

Comment: add isset condition like this  example if(isset($new_array2[$n])) { $prescription_array=explode('/',$new_array2[$n]); }

Answer (score 0):

you could use a $count instead of 10 as below:

```
$count = (count($prescription_array)<10)?count($prescription_array):10;
```

this will assign 10 to $count if your array has more than 10 elements else it assigns the length of the array to $count.
you can now use $count in the condition for the loops.

and as for the outer loop, you could use a try-catch method.

```
try{
//array splitting of $newarray and assignment statement to $prescription_array
}

catch(Exception $e){
break;
}
```